# My loadout isn't loading on most of the servers I go to

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2

Most of the servers I go to says that they have lost connection with something (I can't remember) And that includes my taunts, hats **and** weapons! IS there any way I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The item server is probably down. This means TF2 is under maintenance.

You're best just to wait an hour or two.